# Start service after AWS user-data has run

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

I am building an AMI based off of an Ubuntu 16.04 AMI.

When I start an instance from my AMI, I would like to pass in a user-data script that runs before the service start up on the AMI.

It looks like the user-data is run in `cloud-final.service`. If I `systemctl status cloud-final` or `journalctl -u cloud-final` I see the output of my user-data script.

I tried to set up my .service file to start the service after cloud-final.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=network.service
After=cloud-final.service

...
```

but cloud-final has `RemainAfterExit=yes`, which means it never completes, so my service never starts.

How can I configure AWS Ubuntu to start my service *after* the user-data script has been run?

Comment: If all fails, you could have the script trigger a new target or start your service

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
[Unit]
…
After=cloud-final.service
…
[Install]
WantedBy=cloud-init.target
```

I ran into this as well. `journalctl` showed user data stuff running after `multi-user` and before the target `cloud-init` was reached.

```
<timestamp> <ip_addr> systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
[snip]
<timestamp> <ip_addr> systemd[1]: Starting Execute cloud user/final scripts...
<timestamp> <ip_addr> user-data[1592]: my user data stuff
[snip]
<timestamp> <ip_addr> systemd[1]: Started Execute cloud user/final scripts.
[snip]
<timestamp> <ip_addr> systemd[1]: Reached target Cloud-init target.
```

So I thought to have it be required/wanted by `cloud-init` instead of the usual `multi-user` target (which *may* be what op had), and it just worked.

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by [vlfig](https://serverfault.com/users/108528/vlfig) works. But, I think that it can be improved.

In my example, I'm trying to run the Puppet agent after cloud-init is finished.

In my case, we wanted Puppet to only run after Cloud Init is done
with its set up. In order to achieve that, we need to modify the setup of
its `systemd` unit.

The default execution order for the services and targets that interest us
is the following:
1. cloud-init-local.service
2. cloud-init.service
3. cloud-config.target
4. basic.target
5. cloud-config.service
6. puppet.service
7. multi-user.target
8. cloud-final.service
9. cloud-init.target

```
(stag) dki@appbackend-i-0f0d3f6abd8520f12:~$ systemd-analyze --no-pager critical-chain puppet.service
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

puppet.service @17.737s
└─basic.target @17.291s
  └─paths.target @17.290s
    └─resolvconf-pull-resolved.path @17.290s
      └─sysinit.target @17.282s
        └─cloud-init.service @14.709s +2.572s
          └─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service @13.872s +832ms
            └─systemd-networkd.service @13.487s +377ms
              └─network-pre.target @13.482s
                └─cloud-init-local.service @6.983s +6.495s
                  └─var-lib.mount @11.888s
                    └─local-fs-pre.target @10.584s
                      └─keyboard-setup.service @6.506s +4.072s
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @6.430s
                          └─system.slice @6.416s
                            └─-.slice @3.772s
```

**Dependency graph**:

[Systemd services dependency graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWzHp.png)

**Note**: The green arrows mean `After=` and the gray arrows mean `Wants=`

By having `puppet.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants`,
`systemd` automatically creates a dependency order of the type `After=puppet.service`
according to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html#Default%20Dependencies

**Dependency graph**:

[Puppet service dependency graph original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ShKH.png)

**Note**: The green arrows mean `After=` and the gray arrows mean `Wants=`

As a consequence, if we try to make it run `After=cloud-init.target`, it
creates a dependency cycle and doesn't start at all.

```
[Mon Jul  9 12:49:01 2019] systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found ordering cycle on puppet.service/start
[Mon Jul  9 12:49:01 2019] systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on cloud-init.target/start
[Mon Jul  9 12:49:01 2019] systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on cloud-final.service/start
[Mon Jul  9 12:49:01 2019] systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on multi-user.target/start
[Mon Jul  9 12:49:01 2019] systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Job puppet.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with multi-user.target/start
```

In order to break this cycle, we need to disable the `DefaultDependencies` directive.
By doing that, we are able to add the `After=cloud-init.target` to the Puppet unit in
order to ensure that it waits for Cloud-Init to be done before it starts running.
Both directives are done by creating the `/etc/systemd/system/puppet.service.d/override.conf`
file, which overrides the package's original configurations without changing its original
content. The advantage of it is that we can upgrade the package keeping the changes to
only the directives we actually need.

**Dependency graph**:

[Puppet service dependency graph afterwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/653zE.png)

**Note**: The green arrows mean `After=` and the gray arrows mean `Wants=`

The resulting execution order is:
1. cloud-init-local.service
2. cloud-init.service
3. cloud-config.target
4. basic.target
5. cloud-config.service
6. multi-user.target
7. cloud-final.service
8. cloud-init.target
9. puppet.service

```
(sand) dki@supplier-integrations-i-035c65e75762aaabd:~$ systemd-analyze --no-pager critical-chain puppet.service
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

puppet.service @43.300s
└─cloud-init.target @43.298s
  └─cloud-final.service @33.272s +10.025s
    └─multi-user.target @33.246s
      └─splunk.service @13.815s +19.429s
        └─basic.target @13.463s
          └─sockets.target @13.463s
            └─docker.socket @13.453s +10ms
              └─sysinit.target @13.436s
                └─cloud-init.service @10.873s +2.557s
                  └─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service @9.182s +1.689s
                    └─systemd-networkd.service @9.034s +143ms
                      └─network-pre.target @9.032s
                        └─cloud-init-local.service @854ms +8.177s
                          └─var-lib.mount @7.587s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @1.391s
                              └─keyboard-setup.service @569ms +822ms
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @564ms
                                  └─system.slice @564ms
                                    └─-.slice @423ms
```

Comment: Annoyingly on Centos 7 AWS image cloud-init.target does not exist ( and possible not any RH7 based distro ) !

Comment: As cloud-init.target appears to just depend on multi-user.target itself using the following override seems to work:[Unit]
After=multi-user.target
DefaultDependencies=no

Answer (score 1):

What you could probably do is have the user-data script write a file signifying it is complete (at the end of the script), and have the other service start after somewhere near the end, say, and have it first monitor the file.  When it notices the file being created (or timestamp being updated, or contents changed, whatever), then start the rest of the service and exit as normal.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle and thanks to some hints found in this thread, I finally came out a solution that seems to work for my AL2-based AMIs.

My use-case:
I have an AMI with an already enabled `install.service` that starts some scripts to fine tune the app.
The end user can use the `aws` tool to dynamically attach some pre-existing EBS volumes via userdata on launch.

Here is the full install.service file in case it might help someone:

```
[Unit]
Description=Post launch, pre-installation service
After=cloud-init.target
DefaultDependencies=no
AssertFileIsExecutable=/usr/local/bin/install-script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/install-script
LimitNOFILE=16384
SuccessExitStatus=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [vlfig](https://serverfault.com/users/108528/vlfig):

I was trying to do this with `pm2`. It has a startup script that creates `pm2-ubuntu.service` so I modified that.

BUT I also found that there was also a symlink inside `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` that needed to be moved to `/etc/systemd/system/cloud-init.target.wants`. So there may be other things like that blocking.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following the advice of the other answers here, but ended up creating dependency cycles.

According to the [cloud-init doc](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html#final)'s:

> For scripts external to cloud-init looking to wait until cloud-init is finished, the `cloud-init status --wait` subcommand can help block external scripts until cloud-init is done without having to write your own systemd units dependency chains.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new service file for your service and set the After property to **cloud-final.service**. Then you can use the **systemctl** enable command to enable your service to start at boot.

For example, create a file **/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service** with the following contents:

[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=cloud-final.service

[Service]
ExecStart=

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Then run **systemctl enable my-service** to enable the service to start at boot.